# Can I say "movies are a popular media"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Can I say "movies are a popular media"?
Similarly can I say like "apples are a popular fruit", "engineers are a popular occupation"?

I'm nor sure whether it's correct to put "are" in front of "a".

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't quite right.

The word 'media' is plural. The singular form is 'medium'. But a movie is not a medium.

You might say,

```
Film is a popular medium. Movies are popular.

Apples are popular. The apple is a popular fruit.

Engineers are popular. Engineering is a popular occupation.
```

The rules are to do with 'number-agreement': An apple **is**... Apples **are**... But there are exceptions to the rules and the US and the UK differ in the way they *observe* the rules.

[This post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338/are-collective-nouns-always-plural-or-are-certain-ones-singular) explains some exceptions to the rules.